# Font vertical alignment discrepancy b/w Chromium web view and Chrome app on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I'm building a Cordova app and I'm wondering why I'm seeing the same font render differently between the Chromium WebView (embedded in the cordova app) and on the Chrome app on Android 4.4.2.

[image: discrepancy]

As you can see, the WebView version seems to bump up the font by a few pixels. Here's the computed styles:

`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-user-select: none;
background-color: #FFF;
border-bottom-left-radius: 7.5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 7.5px;
border-top-left-radius: 7.5px;
border-top-right-radius: 7.5px;
color: #4F9EF7;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-family: Museo-900;
font-size: 20px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
visibility: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 295px;
z-index: 0;`

Why would they render differently if they're backed by the same technology? How might I even detect the different environments and style accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and it seems to be the `line-height` property that's not being used the same in the webview.  I need to have a bigger `line-height` in the webview than in chrome.

chrome & webview version 78.0.3904.96